# Morphing my simple winsock server/client application into simple webserver

Tags: c++, apache, http, webserver, winsock

I've created a very simple c++ server/client program that runs on windows sockets, doesn't implement threads and accepts only one connection, echoes out the client's IP when it connects to the server, has simple chat between the client and the server so far.
I was wondering if i could transform it to a web server that handles http requests from the browser and sends back a response?
I am just asking for a few pointers : tutorials/guides/etc 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 :D

Comment: believe it or not I was looking for this and found it 5 minutes before you replied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, all that was needed for a simple http connection with the browser is to send back an htttp/1.1 respnose with status 200 and few other required lines trough the same socket. Now what is left for me is to structure my program to accept more clients indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many good libraries for C++ Web-Development, but as far as i know the one that is mostly used is:
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

If you really feel like developing a web-Application using C++ then you should probably search tutorials around this toolkit.

There is nothing wrong with developing this in C++ but be warned: You will not find the immense and broad library support you would find for Java, e.g.